# Trigonometric Word Problem in 3D

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, word-problem

The question I am having trouble on is as follows:

"As an Expert Mathematics Witness, you have been presented with a Ballistics Report, and a Police Report as your evidence. Use the information provided within these files to prove who, out of the three suspects, is guilty of the crime."

The pdf files are attached below.[Police Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfFQH.jpg). [Ballistics Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KBpV.jpg)

The additional information given stated that angle W also equaled $ \dfrac{5\pi}{ 12}$. With this, I deduced the measure of the marked lines to be 19.32 meters through the sine law. Things get complicated on triangle VGH. I know that the length of VG is 19.32 meters, and that the angle HVG is equal to $\dfrac{5\pi}{12}$, but that is about it. The diagram is to be looked at in a 3D manner, since triangle VGW is considered on the ground, and triangle VGH is against the building.

My question is, how can I get the length of GH while knowing only one angle and one side length? It is not made clear whether the angle VGH is a right angle.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't get to the links.  "Not authorized".  Maybe others will have more success.

Comment: Nope. No access for me, either. Even were we able to see these PDF files, those links could go stale at any time. Please describe the problem yourself in the body of your question, and provide any necessary diagrams there.

Comment: Sorry about the pdf files. I have replaced them with screenshots of the important information above.

Comment: I can see the files now. I would assume angle $VGH$ is a right angle because it is the angle between the ground and the apartment building.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to assume that angle $VGH$ is a right angle. With that assumption, you can deduce the measure of the third angle, since you know $\theta = \frac{5π}{12}$. Or you could use the fact that $tan\theta=\frac{opp}{adj}=\frac{x}{19.32}$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: Instead of sin, wouldn't tan be more useful? And if I calculate the value of opp, I get a number like 72.1 meters, which is not what I am looking for?

Comment: @Musa Ali -- my bad. I meant tan, not sin. This time the typo was not harmless.

Comment: @Musa -- Since $\frac{5π}{12}$ is equivalent to 75º, that suggests the shooter was looking almost straight down (the angle the shooter was shooting from was only 15º). This means the $GH$ is longer than $VG$. I would double-check your assumptions that $VG = 19.32$.